# Filter out duplicates in excel spreadsheet.

Tags: excel, filter, frequency

I have several thousand rows and a handful of them appear more then one time. I need to be able to filter those out to review them without scrolling through thousands of rows of data.

My data is strings so I can't use a math calculation (at least I don't know how i could). What I need the data to return in this instance is Seattle Symphony (all three times).

```
Atlanta Symphony Orchestra
Kingston Symphony
Seattle Symphony
Seattle Symphony
Seattle Symphony
Orchestra of St. Luke's
Pasadena Symphony Association
```

How do I say, please return only rows that appear multiple times. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another column, starting in row 2 (because row 1 should be a header row), use this formula and copy down (this formula assumes the symphony names are in column A):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1
```

Then filter on that column for `TRUE`